# How to select element text with react+enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Just what it says. Some example code:

```
let wrapper = shallow(<div><button class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button></div>);

const b = wrapper.find('.btn'); 

expect(b.text()).to.be.eql('OK'); // fail
```

Also the `html` method returns the contents of the element but also the element itself plus all the attributes, e.g. it gives `<button class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button>`. So I guess, worst case, I can call `html` and regex it, but...

Is there a way to just get the contents of the element, so I can assert on it.

Comment: is it possible to check as its text length?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't forget that you are passing a node (ReactElement) to `shallow` function, and there is no HTML attribute `class` in React. You have to use `className`.

From React documentation

> All attributes are camel-cased and the attributes `class` and `for` are
>   `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively, to match the DOM API
>   specification.

This test should works

```
const wrapper = shallow(<div><button className='btn btn-primary'>OK</button></div>);
const button = wrapper.find('.btn'); 
expect(button.text()).to.be.eql('OK');
```

Comment: how do you find it if there is no class?  also, what if it's not at the top of the tree on the page?

Answer (score 60):

If you found this while looking for **"includes text"**, try:

```js
it('should show correct text', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.text().includes('my text')).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: For me, this returns `true` no matter what. If you are using this, you should try to purposefully make it fail for your use case. I needed to do a `mount` instead of `shallow` for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I think @louis-barranqueiro has probably answered your underlying question. That is, you want a CSS selector and so you should have been using `className` not `class`.

However, to try and answer the question of how to select an element's text using the actual example you gave:

`let wrapper = shallow(<div><button class='btn btn-primary'>OK</button></div>);`

you'd need to use something like an [object property selector](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#4-object-property-selector), e.g.:

`expect(wrapper.find({ class: "btn btn-primary" }).text()).to.equal('OK');`

or prop syntax:

`expect(wrapper.find('[class="btn btn-primary"]').text()).to.equal('OK');`

(or even more explicitly):

`expect(wrapper.find('button[class="btn btn-primary"]').text()).to.equal('OK');`

Comment: If you carefully read the question, the author tries to select the button with `wrapper.find('.btn');`. Based on that, it's obvious, he wants to use `class` HTML attribute and not a custom HTML attribute. So he has to use `className` React DOM attribute because `class` does not exist in the React DOM API.

Comment: it it possible to make check/boolean check on its text length?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this post when searching for ways to select all/some of the text within a `textarea` within `jest` and `enzyme`. For those who are looking for the same thing, you do can the following to select some text (provided you already know the length):

```
let wrapper;
let textareaNode;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Textarea value="Hello world" />);
    textareaNode = () => wrapper.find("textarea").getDOMNode();
});

it("selects all of the select within the given range", () => {
    textareaNode().setSelectionRange(0, 6);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click"); // this would delete the selection via a ref
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").props().value).toEqual("world");
});
```