# How do I test if a React element contains text in Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Let's say I have a React element:

```html
<p>
    <span class="first-part">
        foo
    </span>
    <span class="second-part">
        bar
    </span>
</p>
```

Using Enzyme, how do I test if the element contains a specific piece of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the entire text and determine if it contains the text using vanilla JavaScript, then test if your discovery is `true` or not via Enzyme:

```js
it('should show correct text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<div />);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('foo')).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Nelu for the original answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277165/how-to-select-element-text-with-reactenzyme#answer-53490555.